# How can I pair an Apple Watch with a jailbroken iPhone 5c running iOS 8.4?

Tags: iphone, ios, software-update, jailbreak, apple-watch

When I attempt to do so, a prompt appears telling me to update my phone's iOS. I am wondering whether there is a workaround; I do not want to lose my jailbreak. Thank you in advance.

Comment: What version of watchOS?  There's minimum requirements for the watch and iOS versions.

Comment: @fbara I am not sure; I don't even know how to check a watch's OS...

Answer (score 1):

WatchOS 2 is supported only on devices running iOS 9 and higher.

The only way to run an Apple Watch using an iPhone running iOS 8.4 is to have an Apple Watch with watchOS 1.x.